# How to show certain y-axis numeric values in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to recreate the following graph for my analysis [image].

But when I try doing it on ggplot, I get the following results[image]. I want the y-axis labels to be like the first picture so that I can zoom/exaggerate the samples that have a downward slope. I tried doing various iterations with scale_y_axis() but I am not sure how to achieve this visualization. I would like to use any variety of the scale (not just 5, 200, 20000) since each of my dataset needs different scales.

Comment: Your question is quite vague, and therefore difficult to answer. That looks like a transformed scale, probably a log scale. Try using `+ scale_y_log10()`. Do be aware that interpretation on the log scale is different. Their x-axis might also be on a log scale, hard to tell. You can use the `breaks` argument to set what axis breaks you want to show.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comment about being vague and difficult to answer, especially without any of your code. You can try to mimic what I have done in this sample data

```
library(ggplot2)

# Sample data with thousands of points
df <- data.frame(x = 1:1000, y = runif(1000, 0, 1))

# Custom y-axis labels
y_labels <- c("5", "200", "20,000")

# Plotting
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0.1, 0.3, 0.9), labels = y_labels)
```